# How convert bitmask to array in SQL (MSSQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, bit-manipulation

There is a bitmask stored as a string in table, like `"1010011"`.

Is there a way to get a list of non-null bits using SQL query?

For example:

```
'1010011' should give 1, 3, 6, 7
'0000111' should give 5, 6, 7
```

Comment: Is your bit mask stored as an int or string?

Comment: As string (varchar). Will update question.

Comment: I get 1010011 - 1, 3, but where did you get the 6 and 7 from?

Comment: @ZoharPeled index of the number where its 1

Comment: It would be far better if you worked with the strengths of your tool rather than working against them. In SQL, ideally each column (within each row) stores a *single* scalar value. Not multiple values crammed together. By using this encoding scheme, you severely limit your ability to e.g. apply meaningful indexes or simple ad-hoc queries.

Answer (score 1):

Using a [CTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) to map bit masks to indexes and a [bitwise and operator (`&`)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174965.aspx), you can get a table of indexes for each bitmask in your table:

Create and populate sample table:

```
DECLARE @BitMasks as table
(
    mask char(7)
)

INSERT INTO @BitMasks VALUES 
('1010011'), 
('0000111'),
('1101000'), 
('1110000')
```

CTE and query:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 64 As BitMask, 1 as IndexOfOne
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 32, 2
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 16, 3
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 8, 4
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 4, 5
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2, 6
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1, 7 
)

    SELECT mask, IndexOfOne
    FROM @BitMasks
    INNER JOIN CTE 
    ON  SUBSTRING(mask, 1,1) * 64 +
        SUBSTRING(mask, 2,1) * 32 +
        SUBSTRING(mask, 3,1) * 16 +
        SUBSTRING(mask, 4,1) *  8 +
        SUBSTRING(mask, 5,1) *  4 +
        SUBSTRING(mask, 6,1) *  2 +
        SUBSTRING(mask, 7,1) *  1    -- convert varchar bitmask to int

        & BitMask = BitMask
```

Results:

```
mask         IndexOfOne
-------      -----------
1010011       1
1010011       3
1010011       6
1010011       7

0000111       5
0000111       6
0000111       7

1101000       1
1101000       2
1101000       4

1110000       1
1110000       2
1110000       3
```

For more information about the bitmask to int conversion, read [this article](http://ariely.info/Blog/tabid/83/EntryId/169/T-SQL-Converting-between-Decimal-Binary-and-Hexadecimal.aspx) by Ronen Ariely.

Answer (score 0):

This is really just a string manipulation problem the following query shows how you can return a comma delimited string of all the set bits in the mask for each record.

```
    DECLARE @table TABLE
    (
         ID INT
        ,Mask VARCHAR(8) 
    )

    INSERT INTO @table
    SELECT 1, '1010011' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, '0000111'


    SELECT          T.ID, T.Mask
                    ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST([Bit] AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
                     FROM (
                                SELECT [Bit]
                                FROM    (
                                            SELECT  1 AS [Bit]
                                                    ,SUBSTRING(Mask, 1, 1) AS [Value]
                                            FROM    @table M
                                            WHERE   M.ID = T.ID
                                            UNION ALL 
                                            SELECT  2 AS [Bit]
                                                    ,SUBSTRING(Mask, 2, 1) AS [Value]
                                            FROM    @table M
                                            WHERE   M.ID = T.ID
                                            UNION ALL 
                                            SELECT  3 AS [Bit]
                                                    ,SUBSTRING(Mask, 3, 1) AS [Value]
                                            FROM    @table M
                                            WHERE   M.ID = T.ID
                                            UNION ALL 
                                            SELECT  4 AS [Bit]
                                                    ,SUBSTRING(Mask, 4, 1) AS [Value]
                                            FROM    @table M
                                            WHERE   M.ID = T.ID
                                            UNION ALL 
                                            SELECT  5 AS [Bit]
                                                    ,SUBSTRING(Mask, 5, 1) AS [Value]
                                            FROM    @table M
                                            WHERE   M.ID = T.ID
                                            UNION ALL 
                                            SELECT  6 AS [Bit]
                                                    ,SUBSTRING(Mask, 6, 1) AS [Value]
                                            FROM    @table M
                                            WHERE   M.ID = T.ID
                                            UNION ALL 
                                            SELECT  7 AS [Bit]
                                                    ,SUBSTRING(Mask, 7, 1) AS [Value]
                                            FROM    @table M
                                            WHERE   M.ID = T.ID
                                            UNION ALL 
                                            SELECT  8 AS [Bit]
                                                    ,SUBSTRING(Mask, 8, 1) AS [Value]
                                            FROM    @table M
                                            WHERE   M.ID = T.ID
                                        ) Mask
                                        WHERE Mask.Value = 1
                                    ) SetBits
                     WHERE ID = t.ID
                     FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
                    .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') List_Output
    FROM            @table T
```

If you want to return your list as a table then you can use a splitter function to help achieve this.  The following splitter function from Jeff Moden should do the job.

```
    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings
    (
       @List NVARCHAR(MAX),
       @Delimiter NVARCHAR(255)
    )
    RETURNS TABLE
    WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
    RETURN
      WITH E1(N)        AS ( SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 
                             UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 
                             UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1),
           E2(N)        AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b),
           E4(N)        AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b),
           E42(N)       AS (SELECT 1 FROM E4 a, E2 b),
           cteTally(N)  AS (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT TOP (DATALENGTH(ISNULL(@List,1))) 
                             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E42),
           cteStart(N1) AS (SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t
                             WHERE (SUBSTRING(@List,t.N,1) = @Delimiter OR t.N = 0))
      SELECT Item = SUBSTRING(@List, s.N1, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@List,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000))
        FROM cteStart s;
```

Then select out the mask value of the record you want and apply the splitter function as follow:

```
    DECLARE @table TABLE
    (
         ID INT
        ,Mask VARCHAR(8) 
    )

    INSERT INTO @table
    SELECT 1, '1010011' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, '0000111'


    DECLARE @mask NVARCHAR(50) = (SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(Mask, '0', '0,'), '1', '1,') FROM @table WHERE ID = 1)

    SELECT *
    FROM    (
                SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS BitNr
                        ,Item as BitValue
                FROM    dbo.SplitStrings(@mask, ',')
            ) Split
    WHERE   Split.BitValue = '1'
```